# How to replace url string with another string and then reload page with jquery?

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome, url, replace

Say I have a url, http://mydomain.com/string1 and I want to replace *string1* with *newstring2* and reload the tab with the new string (reload the tab with the new url http://mydomain.com/newstring2).

I am trying this javascript running in the background but it is not working:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(y,q,p){
  if(q.status=="loading"){
    p.url.replace(string1, 'newstring2');
    chrome.tabs.update(y,{url:p.url})
    }
  })
```

At the moment I am only interested in doing this with Google Chrome browser because that's what I'm testing on right now. Does not need to be cross-browser compatible.

What am I doing wrong? (or is this correct?)

Comment: I notice you got a -1 for your question, I think that is because you are not providing enough information. By background do you mean background script? If so are you working on an extension?

`chrome.tabs` is part of chrome API, it is not available for you to use in a normal client side JS application. You need to work with the window object and just use a simple `window.location = 'http://yourdomain.com/newurl'` to redirect the current window to a new url, after whatever logic you need to trigger the new url.

If you are intending on using the chrome API you need to provide more context.

Comment: Just as a nitpick, your code has an error, the `if` statement is not closed correctly. You need an extra `}` before your last `})`

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need is:

```
windows.location = window.location.replace('string1', 'newstring2');
```

Comment: no I need to use chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener method like above.

Comment: sorry, I need jquery not javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Going back through some old code I have, I think you are missing the section where you access the selected tab?

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(y,q,p){
  if(q.status=="loading"){
    p.url.replace(string1, 'newstring2');
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
      chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url:p.url});
    });
  }
});
```

That should work providing the rest of your code is right.

Comment: It would be better if you linked to a working version, so I can see what you are trying to do and the context.

Comment: I just tried your answer, but it sends page into a redirect loop; just keeps trying to load the page.

Comment: Working version does not mean a version with no errors, the fact the loop is occurring means the function is at least working, it's your logic that's the problem. Every time the page is refreshed it does the redirect. This is why you need to share the entire code